# Why do i get this error: "The website declined to show this webpage"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-xp

I have published my asp.net mvc application as a deployment package and once setup on windows 7 it runs fine. However when trying to do the same on windows xp, I get the error below:

[image]

I am running asp.net v4.0.3 and i have executed "aspnet_regiis.exe -i". I have also enabled "Anonymous access" as can be seen in the screen shot below.

[image]

So I have no idea why it doesn't have permission to view the webpage as no login is required. Here is my published directory structure. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

1st Edit. I've included a screenshot of my user accounts showing the ASPNET account. This account has full access to all the folders but this hasn't made a difference

[image: ASPNET user account]

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you in Windows XP system, need to add the ASP.NET user account and enable the access to the folder.

appreciate if it worked for you. This solved me same.

Comment: I actually didn't think about that. I'll give it a try and see if it works.